# Getting a 404 error to run a Jersey REST

Tags: eclipse, maven, jersey

I am trying to run my first HelloWorld Jersey project ever, read bunch of tutorials on it and I think theoretically it should work but of course I am doing something wrong that the page gives me a 404 error. 
Here is what I have:

I started with a DynamicWebProject in Eclise and using plugins convereted it to a Maven project. And added these to the POM file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then I also added a pretty small class like this to have some Jersey annotations:

```xml
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/plain")
    public String getMessage() {
        // Forward request to service layer.
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

and I also registered Jersey with these in web.XML file:

```xml
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>JerseyREST</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

NOTE: there were already some   created in there, I haven't touched them yet. They are still there.

So with this configuration I did a Run On Server and went to

> `http://localhost:8080/JerseyREST/rest/hello`

but getting a nasty  HTTP Status 404 - /JerseyREST/jerseyrest/rest/hello   error on that.  And I can't figoure out what part I am doing wrong.
Any suggesstions or places I take a look at?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I'd start with going to your server's manager app (if it has one) and seeing whether the application has really been deployed. My other guess is that there's something wrong with the @Produces annotation. I've never heard of an "application/plain" MIME type.

Comment: Yeah it is not listed in Tomcat Manager :(

Comment: Then check your build output, there must be something wrong with your project.

Comment: @Tom: do you know where can I find it in eclispe? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with maven in Eclipse. I'm a Netbeans user myself. I can check it in my STS once I get home, unless your question's already answered by then.

Comment: Do http://localhost:8080/ and http://localhost:8080/JerseyREST/ give you back what you expect? I.e. is your application really deployed?

Answer (score 1):

I followed this link to implement my first Jersey Web Service : [REST in Java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html)
I run it on Tomcat v7.0 and it worked fine. Have you tried it on Tomcat? If not, I suggest you to try it. Sometimes it happened for me that I got 404 error permanently. To fix the error I deleted Tomcat and create a new server wizard and then it works fine.

As @Tom said it may related to `"application/plain"`. Use `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` instead.

You need to add these jar files under /WEB-INF/lib/ :
`asm-3.1`, `jackson-core-asl-1.9.2`, `jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2`, `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2`, `jackson-xc-1.9.2`, `jersey-client-1.11`, `jersey-core-1.11`, `jersey-json-1.11`, `jersey-server-1.11`, `jersey-servlet-1.11`, `jettison-1.1` and `jsr311-api-1.1.1`.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to follow his example yesterday...But he was saying copy Jersey files to that Lib folder, i did that and still my Jersey annotations were unresolved and couldn't fix it, so I said oh well let's use pom...How did you fix it?

Comment: You need to download the jar files from Jersey Home page. I will add the name of jar files in my project to the end of this question.

Comment: these are the three JAR files I copied to that Lib folder:  jersey-server-1.12
asm-3.3.1
jersey-core-1.12

Comment: They are right but not enough. let me know if your problem remained unsolved.

Comment: did you get them all from here? http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#chapter_deps   Did you download the Bundle and had all of them?

Comment: I think that you can find them all in that Link. No I didn't use Bundle. I used exactly the same library which I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>JerseyREST</param-value>
```

the param value should point to the folder where you have created the class.