# Why my imports are not recognized

Tags: eclipse, jersey, eclipse-wtp

Using EClipse, First: I created a Dynamic Web Project and copied soem JAR files ( Jersey Jar files ) to WebContent\WEB-INF\lib folder of that project.

[image]

Then I created a new class and on top of it I used some imports such as these:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
```

but it shows some red X errors next to all of them saying the import cannot be resolved.

That's ALL I have done. Is there any other settings I should do to fix these errors?

Comment: Good to see that you solved your problem : [Error 404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671618/getting-a-404-error-to-run-a-jersey-rest/11673316#11673316)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, make sure you ran "refresh" on the project.  If that doesn't pick up the JARs then navigate to them in Eclipse's Project Explorer, right-click on them and in the popup menu use "Build Path" > "Add to Build Path".

Answer (score 55):

Additional information for Jersey newbies: Those imports come from javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar, which is found in the "api" directory in the Jersey download, not in the "lib" directory with the jersey-*.jar jars.

Comment: This is also exactly the solution I was looking for and it fixed my problem

Comment: Thank you! I tried to get it working for hours and u solved it.